# List View not showing up

Tags: android

I want to know why this SIMPLE list view is not showing up. The error says(in short)-your content must have LisView whose id is "android.R.id.list"...

```
public class MyListView extends ListActivity {
    static final String[] PENS = new String[]{
        "MONT Blanc",
        "Gucci",
        "Parker",
        "Sailor",
        "Porsche Design",
        "Rotring",
        "Sheaffer",
        "Waterman"
        };

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_list_view);

        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, PENS);

        setListAdapter(adapter);

    }


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your XML, change the ID attribute of your `ListView` to the following:

```
android:id="@android:id/list"
```

Since you're using a `ListActivity`, Android expects your Layout to contain a `ListView` with a specific ID. If it's not there, you will get a `RuntimeException`.

Comment: There was a id but i guess "@android:id/list" is A LIST object. Am I right? Thanx it worked.